# Symfony 4 migrations migrate failed during Execution

Tags: symfony, doctrine, database-migration, symfony4, doctrine-migrations

my problem is I want to use the

```
php bin/console make:migration
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

approach of Symfony 4 to update my database instead of using:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update   --force
```

which works fine - to say at least.

But when I use migrations I get all the time the following error on the
doctrine:migrations:migrate command:

[image]

Comment: it literally says right there ... the table you're trying to create already exists.

Comment: yes ok, but when I delete it, it comes again and then, I have the same error. 
And the ext_translations table is not mine. Its Symfony internal table for translations.

Comment: unless you wrote the migrations yourself, I would advise you remove all migrations (like the files too), and then take care your migrations aren't trying to create tables that are created automatically or that exist beforehand.

Comment: So, its a Symfony bug? - when Symfony wanna create again and again ext_translations table. Should I report it?

Comment: no, i think your migrations are ... bad. migrations are used to modify the existing database schema to a new schema. your migrations assume there's nothing and try to create existing tables. that's just completely useless.

Comment: My migrations comes from Symfony: php bin/console make:migration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192101/discussion-between-jakumi-and-slowwie).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `make:migration` command apparently is meant to create the database schema, when there's none at all. ([source](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#migrations-creating-the-database-tables-schema))

`doctrine:migrations:diff` is better suited to create differential migrations.

good luck.